# What machine learning algorithms simulate softmax output of neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

In artificial neural network we can use *softmax* activation function in the output layer to get a probability distribution of multi classes. Do any machine learning classification algorithms other than neural networks can also be used for such multi class prediction?

Answer (score 3):

There may be a lot of models that uses softmax function. The simpler one is the *multinomial logistic regression*.

Given an input vector, this model assigns a score to each class :
$$ score(X_i,class_k)=\beta_k \cdot X_i$$

These score are then converted to probabilities using a *softmax layer*